# Dealing with Missing Values in dataset

Tags: validation, machine-learning, dataset, data-analysis

Upto what extent we should fill the missing values for a feature in a dataset so that it doesnt become redundant ?

I have a dataset which has a max of 42000 observations. There are three features which have around 20000, 35000 and 7000 values missing. Should I still use them by filling these missing values or dump these three features?

How do we decide the threshold for keeping or dumping a feature given the number of missing values of that feature ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can interpolate missing values from nearest samples in dataset, i like this manual for pandas about missing values http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html, it lists many possible techniques to interpolate missing values from known part of dataset.

But in your case, i think that it's better to just remove those 2 first features, because i doubt that there could be any good interpolation for missing values, when you have such big amount of them, almost more than half of all values.

But you may try to fix third feature with missing values.